# How should I configure security on Amazon S3 files if I have enabled a CORS security policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Thanks for looking.

I am new to Amazon S3 and have set up a bucket with about 100K files.  I would like to restrict access to these files from only one domain, so I have set a CORS policy on the bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://www.example.com/*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

## The Problem

Even with this CORs policy in place, I am able to enter an individual file URL directly into a browser and access it, so it doesn't appear that the security is working.

Currently, the security on each file in S3 is set to "Everyone" for read permission.  I would have assumed that the CORS file would override this.  If I remove "Everyone" from the permissions, then I can't access the file at all (even with the CORS policy in place).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CORS configuration will be used only to tell the browser if it can send requests to this domain or not, and with which headers and methods. It will have no impact on S3 authorization.

You can generate pre-signed, temporary URLs for objects that are probably better suited for application managed security.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html for the Java SDK example.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.  Is the pre-signing something that needs to be only done once and stored in a db, or should this be done whenever a page is requested that contains links to S3 files?  Thanks again.

Comment: Whenever a page is requested that contains links to S3 files. That is a very simple security control and does not consider authentication, if that is required, take a look into identity federation using IAM Roles.